# How to run a ipynb notebook function from inside notebook with arguments

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, magic-methods

I have a jupyter notebook function

```
def add_args(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

a = sys.argv[1]  # 0 is file name
b = sys.argv[2]

print("sum of {} and {} is {}".format(a, b, add_args(a, b)))
```

I want to execute this function from within notebook. I want to run only this function and it should print answer like this `sum of 1 and 2 is 3`.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551056/running-a-python-script-in-jupyter-notebook-with-arguments-passing

Comment: Not exactly. I don't have a python script. I have a function inside jupyter-notebook file and i want to run only that function within the same notebook.