# Pass variablle value as parametrs to python fromJupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython

[Running a Python script in Jupyter Notebook, with arguments passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551056/running-a-python-script-in-jupyter-notebook-with-arguments-passing)

```
a = 3
b = 5
!ipython two_digits.py a b
```

Why this is not working ?
How to pass parameters from variables ?

Comment: If `two_digits.py` isn't being treated as the attribute `py` of the variable `two_digits`, why should `a` or `b` be treated as variables in that line?

Comment: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#shell-assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can pass Python variable to IPython command using curly braces or dollar sign prefix

```
a = 3
b = 5
```

```
!ipython two_digits.py {a} {b}
```

or

```
!ipython two_digits.py $a $b
```

Comment: Alternatively, for those who haven't set up the script to read in arguments, you can simply define `a` and `b` in the notebook and use them inside the script if you run the script inside the notebook's kernel namespace interactively using the `-i`. Like `%run -i mysript.py`. **This ability is very convenient for development.** In Jupyter/IPython, `%run`, as opposed to `!ipython`, is more full-featured., see [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) about the `%run` magic. **Plus, `%run` will be sure to use the same environment as the notebook.**